# VB.NET Program App run as administrator

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, security, permissions

I have a VB.NET app that works ok but when I need to save to a file, I get the Denied access to folder because my app is not running as an administrator.

I have tried everything on the NET but my app STILL will not run as administrator.

Things I have done:

- Added manifest file to my app with the `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
- Created a setup program to add the RUNASADMIN entry in the Registry

But to no avail. Basically my app needs to be setup somehow to save to local files in the program's folder.

Any ideas on how I fix this?

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <!-- UAC Manifest Options
        If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
        requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

        Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
        If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
        compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
    -->
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

Comment: Can you post the full config file

Comment: Do you have UAC disabled on the machine you are testing this on? Do you get the UAC prompt?

Comment: The focus needs to be on the folder. So my VB app saves to XML files and unless I run the app in Administrator mode, I can't save to the files. I can read from them. The folder is under the Program Files(x86)

Comment: Turns out after trying embedding, I will need to save the XML files into the appdata directory.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after trying embedding, I will need to save the XML files into the appdata directory and save them there. That way UAC does not interfere.